# Python - string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, loops, indices

I have an issue in querying an API in a loop with error where string indices must be integers, not str.

I was wondering if anyone can advise on below error?

So, here is the error:

```
/home/slauw/lotame_api_test/lotame_api_functions.pyc in audience_stats(config_filepath, date_today)
    185     print("aud_stats begun, current row length = " + str(len(aud_stats.index)))
    186     for i in ids:
--> 187         current_aud_stats = single_audience_stats(config_filepath, i, date_today)
    188         aud_stats = aud_stats.append(current_aud_stats)
    189         print("id " + i + " added, current row length = " + str(len(aud_stats.index)))

/home/slauw/lotame_api_test/lotame_api_functions.pyc in single_audience_stats(config_filepath, audience_id, date_today)
    151     query_string = "statistics/audiences/" + audience_id + "?client_as_group=true&date_range=LAST_30_DAYS&generate_stats=now&device_graph=false&page_count=100&page_num=1&sort_attr=data_date&sort_order=ASC"
    152     query_result = get_query(query_string, config_filepath)
--> 153     audienceStats = query_result["audienceStatsReports"]
    154     statsTable = []
    155     a_obj = {}
```

Basically, what I have done is that I use the audience_stats() function below to loop through single_audience_stats() function.

```
def audience_stats(config_filepath, date_today):
    id_query_string = "audiences?page_count=500&page_num=1&sort_order=ASC&sort_attr=id&or=true"
    id_query_result = get_query(id_query_string, config_filepath)
    audiences = id_query_result["Audience"]
    first_id = audiences[0]["id"]
    print("first id: " + first_id)
    audiences = audiences[1:]
    ids = []
    for a in audiences:
        ids.append(a["id"])
    print("ids: " + str(ids))
    aud_stats = single_audience_stats(config_filepath, first_id, date_today)
    print("aud_stats begun, current row length = " + str(len(aud_stats.index)))
    for i in ids:
        current_aud_stats = single_audience_stats(config_filepath, i, date_today)
        aud_stats = aud_stats.append(current_aud_stats)
        print("id " + i + " added, current row length = " + str(len(aud_stats.index)))
    print("loop complete")
    return aud_stats

def single_audience_stats(config_filepath, audience_id, date_today):
    query_string = "statistics/audiences/" + audience_id + "?client_as_group=true&date_range=LAST_30_DAYS&generate_stats=now&device_graph=false&page_count=100&page_num=1&sort_attr=data_date&sort_order=ASC"
    query_result = get_query(query_string, config_filepath)
    audienceStats = query_result["audienceStatsReports"]
    statsTable = []
    a_obj = {}
    keys = ["audienceId", "audienceName", "averageDailyUsers", "uniques", "pageViews"]
    if (len(audienceStats) > 0):
        a = audienceStats[0]
        for key in keys:
            if key in a.keys():
                a_obj[key] = a[key]
            else:
                a_obj[key] = ""
    else:
        for key in keys:
            a_obj[key] = ""
    a_obj["date"] = date_today
    statsTable.append(a_obj)
    stats_df = pd.DataFrame(statsTable)
    return stats_df
```

Config_filepath basically just the authentication to log into the API and date_today is created through time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d).

get_query() function is basically function which helps connect with the API using the config file.

**-- UPDATE**: So at the end of query_result, I will get 'dict' type.

And here is how it looks like:

```
 {u'audienceAbbreviation': u'',
   u'audienceDescription': u'(hardware, gadgets, accessories, ...) - extend enabled',
   u'audienceId': u'202174',
   u'audienceName': u'XTND_3PD_SGU_ConsumerElectronics',
   u'audienceStats': [{u'availableImpressions': u'0',
     u'clientId': u'7927',
     u'clientName': u'(SGU)',
     u'dataDate': u'20170315',
     u'growth': u'0',
     u'lift30DayUniques': u'0',
     u'linked30DayUniques': u'0',
     u'pageViews': u'13894581',
     u'unified30DayUniques': u'0',
     u'uniques': u'960789352',
     u'universeId': u'1',
     u'universeName': u'All'}],
```

Anyone could help on the above issue?

Comment: Looks like the result of `get_query(query_string, config_filepath)` is a string, instead of the expected dictionary.

Comment: can u tell us the type of query_result, you may do this by executing `print(type(query_result))` Either, it is a list or string!

Comment: The result is a dictionary though. Here: {u'Audience': [{u'Client': {u'ClientType': {u'type': u'NETWORK'}, u'accessToIdGraph': None, u'activateCampaignStats': False, u'address': None, u'bcpCallsEnabled': None, u'behaviorHistoryEnabled': None, u'comscoreEnabled': None, u'contributeToIdGraph': None, u'contributeToModeling': None, u'cpl': None, u'currentDataPayoutContract': None, u'dataBuyer': None, u'dataSeller': None, u'defaultAudienceKeyName': None, u'defaultAudienceSeparator': None } @abhinav

Comment: Interestingly, its dictionary @DanD.

Comment: @slauw Kindly confirm by printing it's type rather than printing variable value to console.

Comment: @abhinav the type is dict.

Comment: @slauw Kindly update your question with complete result of 'query_result' variable.